# Multiple addon domains to point to main domain filesystem

Tags: php, dns, add-on

I have a main domain (www.mysite.com). All the files (source code) are stored within the public_html directory. I added one addon domain (www.mysite.net). By default it points to public_html/mysite.net/ directory. Is it possible that it reads all the files (source code) from public_html directory itself.

Actually I am planning to have multiple addon domains, the source code for all will be same.

Comment: I think this is more a SF question for server configuration, not really PHP related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with PHP - it all depends on what access you have to configure your webserver / add/remove files. Judging from what you've said in your answer you didn't configure the webserver in the first instance - your hosting company did that. Indeed, you don't even mention what type of webserver this applies to.

So while there's lots of things we could suggest (e.g. replace public_html/mysite.net/ with a link to public_html) we don't know what's actually possible with your setup.

Of course this is mostly guesswork - you might be running your own farm of apache servers - in which case you just need to change the DocumentRoot for the vhost.

C.